# complaining to anyone who would listen OF the monstrous injustice

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> Most of this time Mr. Jones had spent sitting in the taproom of the Red Lion at Willingdon, complaining to anyone who would **listen of** the monstrous injustice he had suffered in being turned out of his property by a pack of good-for-nothing animals.
> A quote from *Animal Farm*.

What does *listen of* meaning? I'd say *listen to* instead, and I have googled *listen of* with very few results.

Comment: Yet another case of someone linking the wrong words together.  Jones was complaining 
**to anyone who would listen** of the injustice he had suffered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're parsing the sentence incorrectly.

Mr. Jones is **complaining of** the monstrous injustice.

Who is he complaining to?  **to anyone who would listen.**

The phrasing of the sentence is a little confusing because *to anyone who would listen* is inserted parenthetically.  Think of it as "he was complaining - to anyone who would listen - of the monstrous injustice".